# Can I use the same decorator on a class method and on a static method?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a decorator that I use on some class methods. It looks like this

```
def api_caller(logger_name):
    def api_caller_decorator(method):
        @wraps(method)
        def caller_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            logger = log_wrap(logger_name)
            kwargs['api'] = create_api_instance(kwargs['api'])
            logger.info('worker authenticated')
            return method(self, logger=logger, *args, **kwargs)
        return caller_wrapper
    return api_caller_decorator
```

I want to use that decorator outside of the class, is there a way to do it without redefining and manually excluding the `self` argument?

Comment: Is `logger` always the second parameter?

Comment: For the cases that I want to use the decorator on the logger is always needed. I made it keyword argument so that the order can be changed

Comment: In that case just ignore the fact that `args[0]` is `self`, then it will work with or without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not using `self`, you can include it in the optional args:

```
    @wraps(method)
    def caller_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return method(logger=logger, *args, **kwargs)
```